# Memory allocation on declaration vs allocation inside method (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, memory-management

What is the difference between the following two codes in terms of the segment of memory allocation? In fact I want to know if arrays are allocated in the same exact memory segment or not.

```
public class A{
 int[] arr;
 void foo(){
  arr = new int[100];
 }
}
```

and

```
public class A{
 int[] arr = new int[100];
}
```

Comment: First version creates array when you call `foo` method where as the second version creates array when the class is loaded.

Comment: I know that, but I meant if the allocation segment on the memory is the same or not

Comment: What do you mean, "memory segment"?  (It'll all go onto the same heap...)

Comment: Ok, thanks, if that's the case then there is no difference at all. I asked because I thought that like c/c++ if the compiler knows the size of array from the beginning it might be allocated in data segment

Comment: There is no such thing as "memory segment" in JVM specification. Both arrays are stored on Heap just like any other object in Java.